# Member vs Non-member operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am trying to understand operator overloading in C++ and I ran into this piece of code:

```
class Imaginary {
    double re,im ;
    public:
    Imaginary ( double r, double i=0 ) : re(r), im(i) {}

    Imaginary operator - ( void ) const;                // member
    Imaginary operator + ( const Imaginary& x ) const;  // member

    friend Imaginary operator + ( double a, const Imaginary& b ); // non-member ?
};
```

which supposed to show the use of `non-member` overloading. But I don't understand how is it non-member when it's declared inside of class? Or does it depend on the number of parameter, as `+` is binary operation, so with 2 parameters it's considered non-member and with 1 member?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `friend` declaration is injected into the namespace surrounding the class definition where it appears. That is, the declaration (namespace added to later clarification):

```
namespace foo {
    class Imaginary {
        // ...
        friend Imaginary operator+ (double a, Imaginary const& b);
    };
}
```

Actually does two things: it declares a function and it states that this function is allowed to access all members of the class `Imaginary`. The function declared is

```
foo::Imaginary foo::operator+ (double a, foo::Imaginary const& b);
```

Comment: Oh now everything is clear, I just didn't understand how `friend` actually works.. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This line declares `op+` as a non-member friend. Meaning that despite it being a non member it can see Imaginary's private members.

```
friend Imaginary operator + ( double a, const Imaginary& b );
```

The implementation of the operator will be outside of the class.

Answer (score 0):

There is a big difference between these two operators

```
Imaginary operator + ( const Imaginary& x ) const;  // member

friend Imaginary operator + ( double a, const Imaginary& b ); // non-member ?
```

In the first class member operator the left operand is always of type Imaginary. The second operand can be of type double because there is conversion constructor

```
Imaginary ( double r, double i=0 ) : re(r), im(i) {}
```

that allows implicitly convert a double value to an object of type Imaginary.

The friend operator allows to specify a double number as the first operand of the operation. Again if a double number will be specified as the first operand the conversion constructor will be called and in fact you will get expression

Imaginary + Imaginary.

Thus the friend operator appends the class member operator allowing the following expressions

```
Imaginary + Imaginary // class member operator will be called
Imaginary + double// class member operator will be called
double + Imaginary // the friend operator will be called
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, although this wasn't exactly my problem. I just didn't understand why some non-member methods are declared outside class scope, and others (in this case the friend method) inside. So the problem was the friend key word rather than overloading. But thank you again for such thorough answer!

Comment: In fact in this particular case it would be enough to declare one friend operator with two operands of type const Imaginary &.